# what should I do to make the azure openai return stream events with java 11

Tags: azure, azure-openai

I am using this code to return a stream response when using azure openai api:

```
public void getChatCompletion(SseEmitter emitter, String prompt, String azureOpenaiKey) {
        String endpoint = "https://xxxx.openai.azure.com/";
        String deploymentOrModelId = "xxx-ai";
        OpenAIClient client = new OpenAIClientBuilder()
                .endpoint(endpoint)
                .credential(new AzureKeyCredential(azureOpenaiKey))
                .buildClient();
        List<ChatMessage> chatMessages = new ArrayList<>();
        chatMessages.add(new ChatMessage(ChatRole.SYSTEM).setContent("You are a helpful assistant."));
        chatMessages.add(new ChatMessage(ChatRole.USER).setContent(prompt));
        ChatCompletionsOptions options = new ChatCompletionsOptions(chatMessages);
        options.setStream(true);
        options.setModel("gpt-3.5-turbo-0613");
        IterableStream<ChatCompletions> chatCompletions = client.getChatCompletionsStream(deploymentOrModelId, options);
        chatCompletions.forEach(completions->{
            try {
                emitter.send(completions);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("send emit message error", e);
            }
        });
    }
```

this code works but I found it is not a stream result, it still look like a http reqeust, send a request and return the full response onece, is it possible to return the response words by words? I have already read the official demo: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/ai-openai-readme?view=azure-java-preview#chat-completions. Am I missing something? This is my java dependencies using gradle:

```
implementation'com.azure:azure-ai-openai:1.0.0-beta.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a better way to return stream response, change the client to async to get fast response:

```
public void getAsyncChatCompletion(SseEmitter emitter, String prompt, String azureOpenaiKey) {
        String endpoint = "https://xxx.openai.azure.com/";
        String deploymentOrModelId = "xxx-ai";
        OpenAIAsyncClient client = new OpenAIClientBuilder()
                .endpoint(endpoint)
                .credential(new AzureKeyCredential(azureOpenaiKey))
                .buildAsyncClient();
        List<ChatMessage> chatMessages = new ArrayList<>();
        chatMessages.add(new ChatMessage(ChatRole.SYSTEM).setContent("You are a helpful assistant."));
        chatMessages.add(new ChatMessage(ChatRole.USER).setContent(prompt));
        ChatCompletionsOptions options = new ChatCompletionsOptions(chatMessages);
        options.setStream(true);
        options.setModel("gpt-3.5-turbo-0613");
        Flux<ChatCompletions> chatCompletions = client.getChatCompletionsStream(deploymentOrModelId, options);
        chatCompletions.subscribe(chatCompletion -> {
                    try {
                        SseChatService.getInstance().appendMsg(chatCompletion, RequestContext.getRequestId());
                        emitter.send(chatCompletion);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        log.error("send emit message error", e);
                    }
                },
                throwable -> {
                    log.error("flux response facing error:", throwable.getMessage());
                },
                () -> {
                    emitter.complete();
                });
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide full code sample? I am currently on same stuff (but I am newbie in Java). Thanks!

Comment: this is the full code sample, the outer level function you should implement by yourself.